# jQuery select input elements in a target form with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, jquery-selectors

I have several forms in one page, and I wanted to target all input fields in a target form (form ID) that has a certain class in it (Eg."has-error" ).

I though this would do the trick:

```
target_elem = "#form_b";
$(target_elem + ":input").hasClass("has-error").removeClass("has-error");
```

No luck so far. I've tried playing w/ filtering as well. tsk

Comment: What do you think `#form_b:input` will select? And what will `hasClass` return? Did you read the documentation at all? http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6xfeR/1/)**

Simply Use [`.class`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector:

```
$(target_elem + " input.has-error").removeClass("has-error");
```

Comment: The best ; even if I'm don't know if the class selector is really useful. We could apply `removeClass` to all inputs in the target element also... Wonder which solution is the fastest.

Comment: Instead of finding/searching for all inputs in the DOM this would only search for those input with the given class

Comment: Yes but the `target_elem` is already an ID, so the search won't by in the entire DOM. For a small number of input to update, I should be faster not to search by class.

Comment: This was a very elegant solution. thanks pete. and thanks all for participating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Let me know if it helps :

```
  $(".has-error").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("has-error");


  });
```

Live example : http://jsbin.com/yudaseqe/1/edit

Answer (score -1):

No need to use ':'
`$(target_elem + " input").hasClass("has-error").removeClass("has-error");` should work

Note that you also can forget about `hasClass("has-error")` 
It will take more time to find input with this class than deleting this class of every input without checking if it exists.

```
target_elem = "#form_b";
$(target_elem + " input").removeClass("has-error");
```

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
$("input[class*='has-error']",$(target_elem)).removeClass("has-error");
```

Or use this

```
$("input.has-error",$(target_elem)).removeClass("has-error");
```

Comment: Performances of `*=` are really bad compared to the class selector !